# how request.getparameter() take special characters like #,%,& etc

Tags: java

I pass some parameters in ajax URL and want to get that parameters by `request.getParameter();` in controller if that parameters have some special character like `#`,`%`,`&`, etc. then how to get it?

```
String xyz = new String(request.getParameter("XYZ").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: For me its always return null value for request.getParameter("XYZ") so i can't use getBytes("iso-8859-1"). Do you have other solution,i also tried to encode the value before sending it to server but still i am getting null value

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1.Encode values to JSON before sending, and decode them on server.

2. Use javascript method encodeURIComponent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: i passed parameters in ajax and get in controller class than how to use java script in java class

Answer (score 0):

I found best solution after spending couple of hours use

```
((String[])request.getParameterMap().get("paramname"))[0]
```

which gives me param value with special charater